# Pulling a base64 encoded string from http request in php

Tags: php, slim

**Background**

I wrote a small test to make sure I could pull the data from a POST request made from my mobile application. It works fine,

```
$rawJsonObj = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode( $rawJsonObj, true );
$decodedData = base64_decode($json['data']);
file_put_contents('student-data/'.$json['username'].'.txt', $decodedData);
```

Then in my `Slim Framework` app I try the same logic and the actual data that I use to create the file with is null. But I can still access the username and password that are sent in the request.

```
$app->post('/api/v1/endpoint', function ($request, $response, $args) {
   $rawJsonObj = $request->getParams();
   $json = json_decode( $rawJsonObj, true );
   $decodedData = base64_decode($json['data']);
   file_put_contents('test.txt', $decodedData);
return $response; 
}
```

The username and password are showing in the request and I can see them when I write the data in the request to a file.

```
 $data = $request->getParams();
 file_put_contents('2.txt', $data);
```

Data that is wrote to file,

```
","username":"myuname","password":"myPword"}
```

But the base64encoded string is missing,

**Example**

In Swift I am creating the dict like this, then POST it as json,

```
let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "username": named,
    "password": password,
    "data": data.base64EncodedString()
]

if let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: []) {
    request.httpBody = json
}
```

**Question**

How do I access the actual `"data": data.base64EncodedString()` from the request body in `Slim Framework 3`?

I assume this has to do with the way `$rawJsonObj = file_get_contents('php://input');` actually handles the data compared to Slim?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the first snippet shows that JSON is not a param of any kind. It's the request body.

Comment: You mean in the test? But I am POSTing JSON so would it not be JSON in the request body?

Comment: Never mind. I've just had a look at the implementation of `getParams()` and it should really return both. Are you sending a `Content-Type` header to tell it is actually JSON?

Comment: No I am not, I am just passing JSON to the request.httpBody in swift. But I did just get it working using $rawObj = file_get_contents('php://input'); in the slim route. Is that not a really crappy way of doing this though? Should I not be able to access it from the request body?

Comment: Well.. [getParams()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.8.1/Slim/Http/Request.php#L1206) calls [getParsedBody()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.8.1/Slim/Http/Request.php#L1019), which depends on `Content-Type` for auto-detection. It's the price for such commodities. Can you call `$request->getBody()` instead?

Comment: Omg thank you so much. You were so so right. I added the correct headers in the swift request and it worked like a charm. Crazy

Comment: Does getBody() work too?

Comment: I am actually testing that now without the file_get_contents. I will update you in one sec

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes it works now just by access getParams() then decoding the data key $student_data['data'] = filter_var($data['data'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $studentDataDecoded = base64_decode($student_data['data']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Request::getParams()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.8.1/Slim/Http/Request.php#L1206) is a custom method by Slim (not part of PSR-7) that collects all input data; in other words, it's a rough equivalent of PHP's `$_REQUEST` superglobal. Internally, it grabs the request body with [Request::getParsedBody()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.8.1/Slim/Http/Request.php#L1019) (this one, part of PSR-7). Here's where major differences with `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` arise:

> If the request `Content-Type` is either
>   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`, and the
>   request method is `POST`, this method MUST return the contents of
>   `$_POST`.
>
> Otherwise, this method may return any **results of deserializing the
>   request body content**; as **parsing returns structured content**, the
>   potential types MUST be arrays or objects only. A `null` value
>   indicates the absence of body content.

While `$_POST` only decodes standard form encodings (thus in your test code you need to fetch and parse data manually) `getParsedBody()` tries to decode other encodings but, just like `$_POST`, it needs a proper `Content-Type` to do so. If you send one from your mobile app:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

... it'll work as expected because Slim has a builtin JSON decoder.

If you can't send an encoding declaration, you need to decode stuff manually. In this case, the PSR-7 way to fetch the raw request body is [Message::getBody()](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.8.1/Slim/Http/Message.php#L278), that returns a **stream** (more specifically, a `Stream` object that that implements `StreamInterface`).